# Counting sub matrix with all prime numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, dynamic-programming

I am given an NxN matrix. A submatrix is considered special if it satisfies the following condition:

1. It must be a square in shape
2. All numbers must be prime.

I have to count the total number of submatrices of the given matrix that satisfies the following criteria.

For example, let sample input be=>

```
3
3 5 6
8 3 2
3 5 2
```

Sample output: 8

Explanation:

- 1x1: There are 7 prime numbers and every 1x1 matrix contains 1 prime number
- 2x2: only the bottom right submatrix contains all primes
- 3x3: No 3x3matrix satisfies these criteria

So the final answer is  (7+1+0)=8

I recently came across this question in an interview. And I could come up with a brute force solution. What is the best way to solve this question?

[UPDATE]
I have pasted my attempt to solve the problem.

```
class TestClass 
{
    public static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        if(n<2)
            return false;
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(n);i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static boolean scan_matrix(boolean a[][], int start_i, int start_j, int n)
    {
        for(int i=start_i;i<start_i+n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=start_j;j<start_j+n;j++)
            {
                if(!a[i][j])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static int count_valid_matrix(boolean a[][], int n, int N)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int start_i=0;start_i<=N-n;start_i++)
        {
            for(int start_j=0;start_j<=N-n;start_j++)
            {
                if(scan_matrix(a, start_i, start_j, n))
                    result += 1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        boolean a[][] = new boolean[N][N];
        int result = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<N; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                int num = s.nextInt();
                a[i][j] = isPrime(num);
                if(a[i][j])
                    result += 1;
            }
        }
        int n = 2;
        while(n<N)
        {
            result += count_valid_matrix(a, n, N);
            n++;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: looks like a good candidate for a dynamic programming algorithm. A 2x2  matrix is really 4 1x1 matrices that are adjacent to each other which means fundamentally if you solve the problem for the smaller matrices, and save relevant info, it should build up.

Comment: Hint 1: Every 2x2 submatrix contains four 1x1 submatrices. Every 3x3 submatrix contains four 2x2 submatrices. Hint 2: [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 2):

Here's part of one possible formulation. Let `is_special(I, J, W)` represent whether the matrix cell `m(I, J)` is the bottom right corner of a valid square of width `W`. Then:

```erlang
is_special(I, J, 1) ->
  is_prime( m(I, J) );

is_special(I, J, W) ->
  (I >= W - 1 andalso                     % assuming I starts from 0
    (J >= W - 1 andalso                   % assuming J starts from 0
      (is_special(I, J, W - 1) and
       is_special(I - 1, J, W - 1) and
       is_special(I, J - 1, W - 1) and
       is_special(I - 1, J - 1, W - 1)))).
```

Answer (score 1):

## Idea

First, transform (a you did) your matrix into a 0/1 matrix,
with a `0` for non prime numbers and a `1` for prime numbers.

Now, you have a "surface" of `1`s. How many squares can you put in this surface? 
Think of this: if you have a `3*3` square of `1`s starting at `(0,0)` then you already 
know that the squares `(1,0)-(2,1)`, `(0,1)-(1,2)` and `(1,1)-(2,2)` are composed of `1`s, thus you don't have to check again those squares.
Hence, you will look for squares of `1`s starting at `(1,0)`, `(0,1)` or `(1,1)`, *only if they are bigger than* `2*2`.
Imagine the biggest square starting at `(1,0)` has a size `3*3`, but the two other are `2*2`. 
You can ignore the latter (they don't add anything new), but you have to add the new `3*3` square and remove the overlapping surface with the previous one.

This can be generalized as follows:

- store the largest square size starting at `(0,0)` in a matrix `M`
- let `N` = the number of subsquares in a square of size `M[0,0]`
- for every `(r,c)`, from left to right and top to bottom:

  - get from `M` the largest square size starting at `(r-1,c)`, `(r,c-1)` or `(r-1,c-1)`, let's say `K`

    - compute the largest square size starting at `(r,c)` (start at `K-1`)
    - if `M[r,c]` = `K-1`, do nothing
    - if `M[r,c]` > `K-1`, update `N`: `N` += the number of subsquares in a square of size `M[r,c]` - the number of 
          subsquares in a square of size `K-1`

The trick is that "compute the largest square size starting at `(r,c)` (start at `K-1`)" will spare numerous comparisons.

## Pseudo code (Python like)

First, note that a square of size `k` contains `k^2` squares of size `1`, `(k-1)^2` squares of 
size `2`, ..., `1` square of size `k`. This is a well known sum (I took the result from wikipedia!):

```
subsquares_count(k) = 1/6*k + 1/2*k^2 + 1/3*k^3
```

Compute the size of the largest square of `1`s staring at `(r, c)` is not not difficult. I add a begin from `K`:

```
def largest_square_size(m, r, c, K):
    k = K
    while k<n:
        # check the border
        for l in 0..k:
            if m[r+k, c+l] == 0 or m[r+l, c+k] == 0: # consider the left and bottom borders
                break while
        if m[r+k, c+k] == 0 # don't forget the corner
            break while
        k += 1
    return k
```

Now, the sketch of the main loop:

```
for r in 0..n:
    for c in 0..n: 
        K = max(M[r-1,c-1], M[r-1,c], M[r,c-1]) - 1 # add boundary check, K = 0 if r,c = 0,0
        M[r,c] = largest_square_size(m, r, c, K)
        if M[r,c] > K:
            N += subsquares_count(M[0,0]) - subsquares_count(K)
```

DISCLAIMER: I did not test this and there are maybe edge cases, but I think it is correct.

It is clearly suboptimal since some positions may be checked more than once, but it should perform good.